# Training advice to maintain run pace when you have less time

Tags: running

I'm training 4-5 times a week for a 10K race, I gave myself a target pace that I can probably achieve. The race will be in 2 weeks, then I'll add a couple of trail races 3 weeks and 6 weeks later (11km with 300m positive gain, then 12km 500+).

After these races I won't have time to train regularly for a few months due to my job. I'll struggle to find (less than) 1 hour no more than twice a week, but I would like to keep my pace after all the training I've done.
Is it possible to keep the acquired running pace for a few months with lower training?

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on you. The only real answer I believe would be:

Do as much running as is possible to get as close to maintaining your times. Make sure you adjust your diet as your TDEE will go down now you are doing less exercise per week.